# How do I link my project to an external jar in Android Studio without exporting it in the build product?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to link to a system jar. However, I do not want to export that system jar with the apk built by Gradle in Android Studio. If I do, I encounter conflicts with the jar loaded by the system.

In Eclipse I would accomplish this by placing the jar in a folder separate to the libs folder, and adding it to the build path. I would then uncheck the file in the export section.

My question is, how do I link my Android application to an external jar without exporting the jar in my apk, using Android Studio/Gradle?

Comment: `provided` instead `compile`/`runtime` in `dependency` section?

Comment: If I add a compile files(my jar path) to the dependencies section, the apk built contains the classes from the system library. That is, they are exported with the apk. I need to prevent this and still compile.

Comment: Ignore my comment. I now understand what you were saying.